# What does the error SOAP_STOP imply?

Tags: gsoap

I am looking at some code that looks like the following

```
if (soap_begin_serve(pImpl))
{   
    if (pImpl->error >= SOAP_STOP)
    {   
        // TODO.
    }   
    return pImpl->error;
}
```

and trying to figure out what to do in the TODO section there.  Any ideas on what SOAP_STOP means?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few clues to what SOAP_STOP does scattered about the various gSOAP support sites. The best clues are [here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2789290&group_id=52781&atid=468021) and [here](http://gsoap.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.7.9l/httpform_8c-source.html). It appears that any gSOAP error from 1000 on up is meant to tell the gSOAP engine to stop further processing.